# Taking a data frame sample using Limit in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
schema_comment= StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("date", DateType(), True),
    StructField("comment", StringType(), True),

])


commentdf = (
    spark.read.limit(50)
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .schema(schema_comment)
    .load("hdfs:///data/ghcnd/comment.csv")
)
```

I have a defined schema and am looking to bring the first X rows in using the limit function but I must be using it wrong.

I tried placing .limit() after .read and received a DataFrameReader object has no attribute limit.

I've tried defining the DataFrameReader object and then using limit before show() but that takes so long that it seems that it's still loading the entire DF into memory.

How should I be using limit() to only fetch X rows?

Answer (score 1):

Error was simply the location of the limit().

Should be:

```
commentdf = (
    spark.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .schema(schema_comment)
    .load("hdfs:///data/ghcnd/comment.csv")
    .limit(50)
)
```